# Does copy of an object through copy constructor get the same instance variable as the original object?

Tags: java, object, copy-constructor

Does a copy of an object with object instance  variables   get the same instance variable as the original object? if so, I was wondering if the original and copy objects are referencing to the same instance variables.

Comment: If they are `int`s (or any other primitive), no. If they are reference types, it depends on the implementation of the copy ctor.

Comment: A copy constructor is code that a human being writes.  So, the answer depends on the code in the body of the constructor.  If you show some example code, we can provide a clear answer.

Comment: Yes, as @AndyTurner mentioned You might need to read about cloning types i.e,  deep and shallow cloning

Comment: @Coder, did you mean to *edit your question* to include that code?

Comment: Be careful about the word "cloning", which many in the Java world will take to mean use of the `Object#clone` method. That method is one way to create a copy of an object, but has tricks and pitfalls, including the deep/shallow copy matter that @YohannesGebremariam mentioned. Copy constructors and copy methods that aren't based on `clone` also have to deal with deep vs. shallow copies, but can avoid some of the complexities of `clone`.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike C++, Java does not provide copy constructors automatically.  There is therefore no general answer to any question about the behavior of copy constructors, as Java places no restrictions on their behavior.

Nevertheless, every object, however initialized, has its own instance variables.  These are not shared with any other object; they can be "the same" as another object's only in the sense of holding the same value.  Variables of primitive type such as `int` are wholly independent of each other.  Any two variables of reference type may hold values that *refer to* the same object, however, provided that their declared types are both compatible with the class of that object.  A copy constructor could easily create such an effect, but in no way does one need to do so.